# how to check the location text which is visible or not in screen for checking the expect text using if statement

Tags: protractor

I am writing a method for the error message validation for various text box in a single screen. eg: name field error message **this his field must only have letters, numbers, space, or any of -'\"._+!@#$%&*^** and another field error message is **This field must contain only letters, numbers, and spaces**. like that having so many text box i need to pass a value in text box and get the error message for validation i am attaching my script

```
unsupportedCharacters(ele): any{
    if (errormessage == expect(element(by.id("nameError")).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy()) {
        expect(errormessage.getText()).toBe("This field must only have letters, numbers, space, or any of -'\"._+!@#$%&*^")
    } else if (errormessage == expect(element(by.id("codeError")).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy()) {
        expect(errormessage.getText()).toBe("This field must contain only letters, numbers, and spaces");
    }
```

Comment: Make your question clear and share your error and locator details.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsupportedCharacters(ele): any {

    let messages = [
        "This field must only have letters, numbers, space, or any of -'\"._+!@#$%&*^",
        "This field must contain only letters, numbers, and spaces"
    ];

    let targets = [
        element(by.id("nameError"),
        element(by.id("codeError")
    ];

    let promiseArr = targets.map((ele)=>{
        return ele.isDisplayed();
    });

    return Promise.all(promiseArr).then((res)=>{
        res.forEach((dispalyed, index)=>{
            if(dispalyed) { 
                expect(targets[index].getText()).toBe(messages[index])
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: What should be the value of the parameter "ele" that has to be passed to the above method?

Comment: Please read JavaScript Array doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map